# Ask a javascript about inserting body elements to determine the date

Tags: javascript

I want to implement a function as follows

There is a function such as

```
const FloatRed = (startDate, endDate, imgUrl) => {}
```

StartDate is the start date. When the start date arrives, insert an img element into the body

EndDate is the end date. When the end date arrives, destroy the img element

How to realize it? Thank you

For example,

```
FloatRed ("2023-02-06 14:00", "2023-02-06 14:05", "xxx. com/xxx/xxx. jpg")
```

I wrote a simple version

But I think it's always strange. Although it can basically meet the needs, I hope to give some suggestions and help improve it. thank you

```
let Is = false
let t = null;

const FloatingRed = (startDate, endDate, Imgurl) => {
    let nowDate = new Date().getTime()
    let startDate_s = new Date(startDate).getTime()
    let endDate_s = new Date(endDate).getTime()
    let ImageObj = new Image();
    let Dom;

    ImageObj.onload = (e) => {
        Dom = `<div id="FloatRedImg"><img src="${Imgurl}" width=${ImageObj.width} height="${ImageObj.height}"></div>`
        let Dom_old = $("#FloatRedImg").html()
        if (nowDate >= endDate_s) {
            $("#FloatRedImg").remove()
            clearInterval(t)
        }

        if (Dom_old) {
            return
        }
        if (nowDate > startDate_s) {
            $("body").prepend(Dom)
        }


    }
    ImageObj.src = Imgurl;
}

t = setInterval(() => {
    FloatingRed("2023-02-06 16:49", "2023-02-06 16:50", "2022102201.jpg")
}, 1000)
```

Comment: JavaScript conventions note: only classes/prototypes start with a capital. Functions and variables use lowerCamelCase for their names, classes/prototypes use UpperCamelCase, and true constants use UPPER_SNAKE_CASE. Sticking to those conventions makes your code much easier to read for anyone who has experience writing code in this language.

Answer (score 0):

If you put `new Date().getTime()` in a variable, it will make the time value constant. I prefer you call `new Date().getTime()` in setInterval, so that time will be updated continuously. Try this with change the `startDate` and `endDate` value :

```js
let Is=false
let t;

const FloatingRed = (startDate, endDate, Imgurl) => {
    let startDate_s = new Date(startDate).getTime()
    let endDate_s = new Date(endDate).getTime()
    let ImageObj = new Image();
    let Dom;

    ImageObj.onload=(e) => {
        Dom = `<div id="FloatRedImg"><img src="${Imgurl}" width=${ImageObj.width} height="${ImageObj.height}"></div>`;
        if (new Date().getTime() > startDate_s && new Date().getTime() <= endDate_s) {
          $("body").prepend(Dom)
        }
        t = setInterval(() => {
          if(new Date().getTime() > endDate_s) {
            $("#FloatRedImg").remove();
            clearInterval(t);
          }
        }, 1000);
    }
    ImageObj.src=Imgurl;
    
}
FloatingRed("2023-02-07 08:45", "2023-02-07 09:00", "https://picsum.photos/200");
setInterval(()=>{
  $('#now').html(new Date().toLocaleString());
},1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="now"></div>
```

Comment: thank you , Your code seems to run with some minor problems. It's time to refresh the image before it comes out